# How to Obtain a Boolean Value for isSignedIn with @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, supabase, next.js13, supabase-database

Hey everyone,

I'm working on a Next.js 13 project, and I'm using `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs` for authentication. In my `layout.tsx` file, I'd like to find a way to check whether a user is signed in or not, and use this information to modify the layout, specifically changing the buttons displayed to the user based on their authentication status.

I came across the method `supabase.auth.getSession()`, which returns the session object. It looks like I can check if the returned session is null to determine the user's signed-in status. Here's what I have in mind:

```js
const isLoggedIn = (await supabase.auth.getSession()).data.session !== null;
```

By determining the logged-in status, I aim to show different buttons in the layout - "Log In" and "Sign Up" for logged-out users, and a "Log Out" button for logged-in users.

I'm trying to implement this logic within my `layout.tsx` file, and I'm wondering if I'm approaching this problem the right way. Does anyone have experience with this approach in Next.js 13 with Supabase? Or is there a common pattern or best practice for handling this scenario? Additionally, if anyone sees any potential issues or better ways to handle this, especially within the layout file, I would be very interested to hear.

Thanks in advance!